# Found scam site that tricks you into giving them more contact info to remove your existing public info

Tags: privacy, information-gathering, scam

I found a site where they display **your** political registration info (which includes contact info) that was requested from the government. If you find your contact information from this [site](http://publicdatadigger.com), do NOT request to remove it. You will be giving them your current phone number and email address, handing them more info than what they have.

I was able to find the site by simply googling my cell phone number. If the site has your info, it will display your **name**, **address(es)** (*possibly outdated*), **phone number(s)** (*possibly outdated*), fake email address, and **political registration info**.

How would one remove his/her info from the site without giving them more info?

Comment: I'm not sure random people from the Internet can help with this one.

Answer (score 1):

Legally?  I don't think that there's a reliable way to know that your info is removed from a scam site.  If it's provided, you can click on an "unsubscribe" link, but all that does with a scam site is validate that you accessed their scam site, setting you up for further attempts.